# Best practice for functions accepting key value pairs as arguments in R?

Tags: r

Some languages have an obvious choice when writing a function that accepts key value pairs and determining which data structure ought to be used (e.g. a hash would be an obvious option in ruby, for example).

In R, there are a few ways that come to mind. Examples:

- as a named list
- as a standard list
- as a named vector
- as a character vector with some regular expression to extubate the key and value from a single string

Is there any one data structure that is recommended over the others or is considered 'best practice'? Or does it totally depend on the use case? E.g. named anything (vector, list) will create limitations (since names have various constraints). Lists tend to be more tricky to traverse than data.frames. Parsing character vectors *could* have unintended consequences if the inputs aren't in a very well understood and consistent format. Etc.

Is there a dominant convention that overcomes each of these issues, or is it simply a matter of selecting the best tool for each unique circumstance?

Comment: It's a good question, but surely runs the risk of being closed as opinion-based. I don't see how you could get a didactic answer to this. FWIW I think a named list is closest to being the general answer - it matches best to the concept of, say, a Javascript "object" or a C++ unordered_map (at least in terms of user interface). But there are exceptions. If you have a specific use-case in mind, it would be best to write your own class if none of the existing ones are exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @AllanCameron, I have a similar question to OP but it has to do with the argument specification of such functions. Would you mind taking a look at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63165166/10841085)? I have included a toy example but I'm not sure if it conveys the problem well enough.