# R - Argument specification for a function that uses key-value(-ish) pairs

Tags: r

I have the following data frame of the colours red, green and blue:

```
r = data.frame(mon = c('green', 'red'), tues = c('green', 'blue'), wed = c('red', 'green'))
r
#     mon  tues   wed
# 1 green green   red
# 2   red  blue green
```

I would like to write a function that allows the user to remove multiple colours of their choice from all columns OR from certain columns of the data frame as specified by them.

The data frame above is contrived in that it only contains three distinct values (red, green and blue). In reality, it may contain any number of values, not known to me at the time of writing the function. However, the format of the data frame never changes, i.e. it always contains three columns named `mon`, `tues` and `wed`.

**What would be the best way to specify the arguments of such a function?**

I'm currently using a simple ellipsis:

```
removeColours <- function(...) {
 colours = list(...)
 colours
}
```

This makes the function flexible enough to accommodate the following use cases:

1. **If the user wishes to remove *all* colours, they can call the
   function without passing any arguments:**

   `removeColours()`
2. **If they wish to remove particular colours, they can pass these
   colours as strings:**

   `removeColours('red', 'green')`

   This removes the colours `red` and `green` from ALL columns in which they appear.
3. **If they wish to remove a particular colour from *certain columns*
   only, they can pass a sort of key-value pair where the value component of
   the pair contains the names of the columns from which to remove the
   colour specified by the key component:**

   `removeColours('red', green = c('mon', 'wed'))`

   This removes `red` from all columns and removes `green` from columns `mon` and `wed` only.

The problem is that in the third case, the resulting `colours` list does not have a uniform structure:

```
removeColours('red', green = c('mon', 'wed'))
# [[1]]
# [1] "red"
# 
# $green
# [1] "mon" "wed"
```

The first element is unnamed and its value is the name of the colour to remove. Whereas the second element is named but its value is the name of columns ('mon', 'wed') from which to remove the colour given by its name ('green'). There's also no way to prevent the user from passing column names but no colour, e.g.: `removeColours(c('mon', 'wed'))`.

Comment: The structure will always be lost in most of the cases. Eg `removeColours('blue')` what should be the list? or even `removeColours('red')`?? There is no way you can maintain it to be a dataframe, Probably you should consider maintainig the dataframe, but turning the specified values into `NA`

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify that the data frame is for illustrative purposes only, it has nothing to do with the function. My question asks how best to specify the arguments of a function that would allow the user to remove all colours, some colours or some colours from certain columns.

Comment: use of an elipsis, is the best way to go. It allows every kind of input including a list

Comment: Yes, but as detailed in my post, the list that results from `list(...)` isn't uniform in case 3.

Comment: the non-uniformity is what makes coding interesting. Try and see how to evaluate that. If defeated, we will help you out

Comment: Maybe I could restrict the user input to be of the form `colour = column`? `column` can either be a subset of `c('mon', 'tues', 'wed')` OR `all` if the colour should be removed from all columns. That way `removeColours('red')` or `removeColours(c('mon', 'tues', 'wed'), 'blue')` would throw an error notifying the user that their input is invalid. But then I don't know how to stop the user from entering something like `red = c('all', 'mon')`.

Comment: No need of restriction. Just check the resulting list. Recall that with ellipsis, every input will be transformed to a list. Loop over this list. If an element has no name, name the element as itself and include all the days ie column names of the df as its elements

Comment: Yes but what if they input something like `removeColours(c('wed, 'mon'))`? I would need additional checks to catch stuff like that which is why I figured restricting the input to `colour = column` would be safer.

Comment: Why remove a day??? In the original question you are only removing colors, not days

Comment: Yes, I'm just trying to think of scenarios where the user might pass invalid input.

Comment: If you pass days, just stop the function. That is the only invalid data. you are supposed to remove the colors not days.